# How to synchronize during destructor

Tags: c++, concurrency, synchronization, destructor

Lets assume you have a class `Ressource` which manages some kind of ressource using RAII in an thread-unsafe manner. `Ressource::~Ressource()` especially is a method which must not be run concurrently (for multiple objects).

Now your `Manager` class, which just holds a bunch of `Ressource`, is perfectly thread-safe. Any call to a method of `Ressource` is wrapped in a surrounding `std::lock_guard`. Everything in your thread-safe world is perfect, except for your dtor. Theoretically we could implement it as

```
Manager::~Manager() {
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock { m_mutex };
      m_ressources.~std::vector<Ressource>();
   }
}
```

Yet this approach will result in double-destruction.

I see two alternative approaches which can work:

1. Wrap `Ressource` in a `ThreadsafeRessource`. This introduces alot of boilerplate code and if we want to synchronize multiple `Ressource` at once (without yielding locks all the time) we would likely need yet another class for collections, whose interface is not straightforward.
2. Wrapping any `Ressource` or collections thereof in `std::unique_ptr`. This allows us to manage lifetime manually but introduces one more indirection. While likely insignificant, this leaves a bad taste anyways.

How would you solve this?

Comment: Why would you need a lock in a destructor? You only need a lock if you need protection against concurrent access, but if some thread is accessing your manager _while it is being destroyed_, you have bigger problems, and locking in the destructor will definitely not solve them! Can you elaborate a bit more what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @mpoeter this is a real-world problem. hdf5 is a c-library without synchronization but which employs reference counting for objects. Any call to any hdf5 function needs to be synchronized globally.

Comment: Could you loop the vector and `std::vector::erase` each element wrapped in a `std::lock_guard`? That's like the other surrounded calls.

Comment: @Manuel This sounds like a reasonable thing to do. I haven't thought about that one yet. Thank you

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve. Your mutex `m_mutex` seems to be a member of `Manager`, so how should this help synchronizing access globally? If I understand you correctly, then you are using the hdf5 library which uses thread-unsafe reference counting, but you want to use it in a multit-hreaded environment. That's why you introduced the Manager class - correct so far? But if your program access resources _only_ via `Manager`, why would you need a lock in the _destructor_? If your program accesses resources _outside_ `Manager`, how does Manager help in the first place?